# RHEVM - How to add three cd drives to server or desktop

Tags: virtual, virtualization, kvm

In RHEVM 3.2 server can have one CD-DRIVE, but how to provide two or more cd drives to virtual server.

Hard disk is attached by 'Virtual Machines -> Select Server -> Disks TAB -> Add' But not able to get idea how to add more CD/DVD or such similar drives to server.

Many thanks!